# Scaled element does not stay scaled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I scale an element with jquery by 50 percent it gets smaller at first and then it returns to the original size.

I guess thats due to the toggle function.

```
$(".target").toggle( "scale", 
          {percent: 50, direction: 'horizontal'}, 2000 );
```

How can I scale and element and stick with that scaled size?

I do NOT want to apply a css class , just with jquery.

Comment: `$(".target").css('width','50%')`? Or use `animate()` if you need a duration.

Comment: width is not scale I need both directions at once.

Comment: By only specifying one dimension the browser will scale the image proportionately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using jquery UI. If so, you have to rewrite your code like this, in accordance to their documentation:

```
$(".target").toggle({ 
    effect: "scale", 
    direction: "horizontal",
    percent: 50 ,
    duration: 2000
});
```

However, this will not give you what you are looking for since `toggle` ends up hiding/showing an element. You need to look into `animate`. The best way to approach this is to wrap your `.target` element inside another `div` then animate by giving a `left` and a `width` at the same time, this should lead you in the right direction:

```
$(".target").animate({
    width: '50%',
    left: '25%'
}, 2000);
```

To help you even further, I created a **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k2shroo8/)**. Check it out.

Comment: the animate widht/height both 50% or an equal value does not result in an equal scale.

Comment: @Pascal check out the Fiddle I provided, and let me know what you think

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle: that is what I wanted   draggable.animate({
                    width: '50%',
                    height: '50%',
                    top: '25%',
                    left: '25%',
                    right: '25%'
                }, 500);   but it behaves terrible in my ui :/

Comment: You're confusing me.. its difficult to figure out your end result. You want something to drag as well?

Comment: yes I drag something and do cursorAt of jquery draggable to center the dragging object and scale it on drag.start. My problem with applying a class is => somehow the toggleClass does not work in inverting both classes start/stop there is sth wrong in my code race condition whatever so I thought I try it without a class.

Comment: tough.. maybe create a fiddle yourself, and point out whats wrong or what you need help with

Comment: I found out using the ui.helper and operate on that object is much better then on the dragging object...